# Bash: reverse octal dump (od)

Tags: bash, shell, posix, octal, od

Once I have octal dumped a file, how can I reverse this process?
I have found several other questions related to this but in all of those cases the choice of flags for the `od` command causes the result to contains hexadecimal characters. Many of them appear to be using the `xxd -r` command to reverse it but even after reading the manual I cannot seem to get it to work with octal.

POSIX compliance would be quite nice but is not strictly required. I'm trying to avoid dependencies if possible for portability.

I am essentially trying to do the following:

```
$ cat hello.txt
Hello World!
$ od hello.txt
0000000 062510 066154 020157 067527 066162 020544 000012
0000015
$ od hello.txt | something_goes_here
Hello World!
```

Comment: If you'll go as far as `od -b` which is octal but bytewise, `od -b file | while read -a x && (( ${#x[@]} > 1 )); do ( IFS=\\; printf "\\${x[*]:1}" ); done` for bash or `| while read a b && [ ! -z "$b" ]; do ( set $b; IFS=\\; printf "\\$*" ); done` for POSIX

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this worked perfectly!